# Override methods in tagbar

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, tagbar

When I have methods in header file, which marked as override, then [Tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar) can not correctly display this: show not name of method, just simple `override`. How I can fix that?

[image]

Comment: Which ctags are you using? Exuberant-ctags?

Comment: @rfkortekaas Exuberant Ctags 5.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/bugs/367/) in Exuberant-Ctags which causes this issue.

This has been solved in [universal-ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags).